# Javascript degradable cascading dropdownlists

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, graceful-degradation

I have 2-3 list within a form that rely on each other. If one is changed an ajax call is made and the others are loaded.
I was wondering if any of you knew of a method to make this dropdownlist js degradable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could break it up into multiple forms, so when the first is submitted, the server will check and then put out the 2nd form.

The Javascript would simply override the submit functions and create/populate the rest on the fly.

Comment: Thanks. that makes sense. Still 1 question though. How would i go about posting the entire form back with all of the selected drop down lists values?